# SharePoint "modern" sites classification return empty

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, pnp-powershell

Using PNP PowerShell, I am retrieving the SharePoint Site classification. I have set the classification on all 10 sites, but for 5 sites it returns the classification and for remaining it returns empty.

I have tried 2 ways to get but both scenario it return empty.

Scenario 1:

```
Connect-PnPOnline $siteUrl -Credentials $cred
$context = Get-PnpContext 
$siteCol = Get-PnPSite  -Includes Classification
$context.Load($siteCol) 
$context.ExecuteQuery() 
$classification = $siteCol.Classification
```

Scenario 2:

```
Connect-PnPOnline $siteUrl -Credentials $cred
$context = Get-PnpContext 
$siteCol = Get-PnPSite  

$classificationValue= Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject  $siteCol -Property Classification

$context.Load($siteCol) 
$context.ExecuteQuery() 
$classification = $classificationValue
```

Some unexpected scenario is happening, some time it return classification and some time not.

Comment: Are they all modern sites?

Comment: Yes, those are Modern site with Site template Group#0

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Get-PnPSiteClassification` cmdlet in PnP PowerShell.

```
Get-PnPSiteClassification
```

**Microsoft official documentation**: [Get-PnPSiteClassification](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpsiteclassification)

**Note**: Check Required Permissions mentioned in documentation before using this cmdlet.